# Unable to launch CameraCaptureTask or PhotoChooserTask while debugging with device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to debug my application on the connected device**(Dell Venue Pro WP 7.0)** but whenever I try to launch `CameraCaptureTask` or `PhotoChooserTask` in my app then nothing happens. Everytime I've to disconnect the device from the Zune and then app works fine. But I want to debug my app on device. I'm not able to figure out what is happening there. No Exception , No Errors ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use the Camera or the Photo Chooser while you're connected with Zune.

Instead, connect the device, shut-down Zune, and start `WPConnect.exe`, and then you can deploy&debug, and still use the Camera, Photo or even Music if you want to.

You can find WPConnect in either the `x86` or `x64` folder in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect
```

Comment: Okay it's working fine. I'm just a noob for WP. **Thank you :)**

Comment: thanks! have been having issues with Zune's presence for a while - this resolved a bunch of my debugging headaches!