# Windows Phone - SavePicture - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Why this code throws InvalidOperationException no metter if I am conncted to PC or not?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
picture.SaveAsJpeg(ms, 480, 800);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
MediaLibrary l = new MediaLibrary();
l.SavePicture("test11", ms);
l.Dispose();
ms.Dispose();
```

I use WP7 RC Tools and XNA
picture is an Texture2D instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem.

I forgot I've played with permissions (manifest file), and accidentaly deleted this permission

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
```

Answer (score 0):

found this example here: [How to: Encode a JPEG for Windows Phone and Save to the Pictures Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

hopefully it helps, it is saving the stream in the IsolatedStorage first then loading from there and saving in the MediaLibrary in the end...

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a file name for the JPEG file in isolated storage.
    String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

    // Create a virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
    var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }

    IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);


    // Create a stream out of the sample JPEG file.
    // For [Application Name] in the URI, use the project name that you entered 
    // in the previous steps. Also, TestImage.jpg is an example;
    // you must enter your JPEG file name if it is different.
    StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri("[Application Name];component/TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

    // Create a new WriteableBitmap object and set it to the JPEG stream.
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; 
    bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

    // Encode the WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
    wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    myFileStream.Close();

    // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
    myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // Save the image to the camera roll or saved pictures album.
    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

    if (radioButtonCameraRoll.IsChecked == true)
    {
        // Save the image to the camera roll album.
        Picture pic = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("SavedPicture.jpg", myFileStream);
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to camera roll album");
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the image to the saved pictures album.
        Picture pic = library.SavePicture("SavedPicture.jpg", myFileStream);
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to saved pictures album");
    }

    myFileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thx, for help but that was not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected to the PC, you can't use the MediaLibrary. Instead connect with WPConnect.exe

See this answer for details on how: [Unable to launch CameraCaptureTask or PhotoChooserTask while debugging with device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568884/unable-to-launch-cameracapturetask-or-photochoosertask-while-debugging-with-devic/7568965#7568965)